# Php strtotime deprication

Tags: php

I know we are now ment to use dateTime class, but it alwasy just gives me an error can anyone help fix this:

Code before:

```
        $dateTime = new DateTime($r["CreationDate"]);
    $lastUpdate = time() - strtotime($r["CreationDate"]);
```

Code After:

```
        $dateTime = new DateTime($r["CreationDate"]);
    $lastUpdate = time() - $dateTime->format("Y-m-d");
```

Comment: `strtotime` is not deprecated. Passing `null` to it is deprecated. If `$r["CreationDate"]` contains a valid value, there is no reason you cannot still use `strtotime`

Comment: `$lastUpdate = time() - strtotime($r["CreationDate"]);` - both `time` and `strtotime` return a number, so subtracting one from the other makes sense here. With `time() - $dateTime->format("Y-m-d")`, you are now trying to subtract a value of the form `2023-10-26` from whatever current number `time` returns, and that of course makes little sense.

Comment: @rickdenhaan Thank you ! Adding a simple if statement to check for null fixed it !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use either [the `getTimestamp` method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php) or [the `U` format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) to get the Unix timestamp from a DateTime object.

```
$lastUpdate = time() - $dateTime->getTimestamp();
$lastUpdate = time() - (int)$dateTime->format("U");
```